# GFCI contacts with two solenoids

Tags: protection

I've finally understood the purpose of the second solenoid in the above GFCI.

[image: 1]

How it works is when Reset was pressed. The contacts come to the top (attracted by the top solenoid). And in the second solenoid (actually the main one), there is a pin with spring that locks the contacts (in top position) into place. When the SCR and main solenoid (the right horizontal one) triggers, it pulled the pin to the right magnetized metal hence the contacts come down (with spring inside). This is an ingenious electronic reset design, I wonder what GFCI receptacle in the USA used it. Mostly you have mechanical Reset only wherein if you press Test, the Reset button would pop up. Why doesn't USA GFCI receptacle used electronic reset too. What is the advantage and disadvantage of electronic Reset button?

original:

A GFCI outlet usually has 1 solenoid only.. such as this Leviton teardown:

[image: 1]

But the following has 2 solenoids,

[image: 2]

I'm double checking and reverse engineering the circuits. Anyone has any idea why two solenoids. The top solenoid probably attracts the contacts upward, but why is there another solenoid on the right.

This is the circuit diagram for both (they use identical chips):

[image: 3]

Comment: Have you perhaps mistaken the current transformers(also wire wound inductors) for the solenoid?

Comment: No the current transformer is just on top of the main sense transformer inside the white thing on the left.

Comment: In most of the ones that I've seen, the "reset" function (re-closing the contacts) is purely mechanical, not electronic. The single solenoid is used only to open the contacts. So yes, all GFCIs have "memory", regardless of whether line power is interrupted.

Comment: But in the above gfci with 2 solenoid. The reset is not mechanical but electronic.. see picture at https://imagizer.imageshack.com/v2/800x600q90/923/jwkKTI.jpg  The top switch is to reset it. the lower switch is to test it. One of the solenoid could be used to close it. But when power is cut, it remains closed.. what kind of relay is it.. what do you think?